# Trying to make two sql queries, but always landing with error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO bus_info(bus_id,route_num,school_name) values('$BusNum','$RouteNum','$SchoolName'); INSERT INTO bus_loc(bus_id,lat,lon) values ((SELECT bus_id from bus_info where bus_info.bus_id='$BusNum'),'$latitude','$longitude')");
```

PHP

```
$BusNum = $_POST["BusNum"];
$SchoolName = $_POST["SchoolName"];
$RouteNum = $_POST["RouteNum"];
$latitude = $_POST["lat"];
$longitude = $_POST["lng"];
```

Database is connected i.e. returned true.`enter code here`

Fails with : 
Error sending data:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `INSERT INTO bus_loc(bus_id,lat,lon) values ((SELECT bus_id from bus_info where b` at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding split query into two parts and use them like :-

```
$query =   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO bus_info (bus_id,route_num,school_name) values('$BusNum','$RouteNum','$SchoolName')"); 

$query2 =  mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO bus_loc (bus_id,lat,lon) values ((Select bus_id from `bus_info` where bus_id = '$BusNum'),'$latitude','$longitude')");
```

Comment: Thats a better and cleaner way! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

From: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php#87203

> mysqli::query() can only execute **one** SQL statement.
>
> Use mysqli::multi_query() when you want to run multiple SQL statements within one query.

How to use `mysqli_multi_query`: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 1):

This query is missing a `where` clause condition

```
SELECT bus_id from bus_info where b
```

change it to like:

```
SELECT bus_id from bus_info where b = 'something'
```

but you should not execute two queries like this but execute this first save the result in a variable and then execute the next one like

```
 $query =   SELECT bus_id from bus_info where b = 'something'
 $saved = $mysqli_query($yourconnection, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc();
 $fetched = row['columnnamehere'];
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO bus_loc(bus_id,lat,lon) values ('$fetched');
```

Comment: I added the 'WHERE' clause
    where bus_info.bus_id='$BusNum'.
Trying your variable method.

Comment: The "where b" reported in the error is just the MySQL server truncating the string at that point for the purposes of reporting an error; if you check the PHP core in the question, you can see that the query has a proper where clause.